# How to get discount amount for corresponding coupon code in magento?

Tags: coupon

How to get the discount amount for corresponding coupon code in magento using magento
programming?

Comment: in the code or via the admin?

Comment: Please edit the question and give an overview what you are talking about and what you want to achieve, then request reopeniong

Answer (score 1):

Under Magento administration, first go to System -> Configuration -> Customer -> Promotions and create initial settings which will be used later for generating coupon codes,

Follow this link, This is what you want. 
http://inchoo.net/magento/create-unique-coupon-code-in-magento/